# TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature

Tags: tfs

I added a new state to Task work item and then changed the state in process configuration. Imported task wit through power tools and then imported process template again.
However I am getting an error "Details about the validation error appear below:

The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'TaskBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Need tech design." Am I missing something ?

Comment: Edit your post to include the relevant work item definition and process configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get this error if you only added the state "Need tech design" under section “TaskBacklog” in configuration file, but didn't add this state in the "Task" work item’s workflow.

To fix this issue, modify the “Need tech design” to workflow states for the work items under Task category and import the configuration file.

Comment: THANK YOU! yes that was the issue :) all set.