# How to enable features in TFS 2017 to configure bugs on task board?

Tags: tfs, kanban

From where can i enable features in 2017 to configure bugs on task board (kanban board)?
[image]

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739438/TF-The-current-configuration-is-not-valid-for-this

Comment: Did you click on the link that takes you to the location where you can enable the feature?

Comment: It looks like your tfs was upgraded without feature configuration. What version did you use before?

Comment: Earlier it was TFS 2015

Comment: @Daniel Mann : its taking to some description page

Comment: Hi @Yan Sklyarenko  : will try the link and update you... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have modified the TFS process template related to bug Work Item type.

So, please update the feature first then check if you have added some extra states and missed in the `ProcessConfig.xml` file or `Categories.xml` file:

Try below steps to fix that:

1. [Configure features with the wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade) first, and [Add updates to team projects manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-features-manually) if needed.
2. Export the ProcessConfig file: ([Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration))

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>witadmin exportprocessconfig /collection: <collectionurl> /p: <projectname> /f:c:\processconfig.xml`
3. Update the `BugWorkItems` section inside the XML and add the missing
   states:

   `<BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory"> 
       <States> 
         <State type="InProgress" value="Not Done" /> 
         <State type="InProgress" value="On Hold" /> 
         <State type="Complete" value="Closed" /> 
         <State type="Complete" value="Not reproducable" /> 
         <State type="Complete" value="Release" /> 
         <State type="Resolved" value="Test AIG" /> 
         <State type="Resolved" value="Test BUS" /> 
         <State type="Resolved" value="Test Failed" /> 
       </States> 
     </BugWorkItems>`
4. Import the updated config again:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>witadmin importprocessconfig /collection: <collectionurl> /p: <projectname> /f:c:\processconfig.xml`

Do the same thing with the `Categories.xml` file. See [Import and export categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-categories?view=tfs-2018) for details.

Then check it again.

Similar thread : [TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517038/tf400917-the-current-configuration-is-not-valid-for-this-feature)

Comment: Thanks for your help :) ,,, will try this solution and update you if worked :)

Comment: Sorry missed to update.. We changes in category config file and worked well .